# Core-Data with a preloaded database

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, swift3

Using `Xcode` (Version 8.3.3) I created a sample app with the template for `Single View Application` and clicking `Use Core Data`.
At this point my app is running and I have a database containing data that I do not want to rebuild each time the app is started.
In other words I have the files:

```
MyApp.sqlite, MyApp.sqlite-shm and MyApp.sqlite-wal
```

I copied those files to the MyApp project folder.

Now here is my question:

***How do I need to change the code so that the app will use the data in the database next time it is started?***

Note: the only code I have related to the question is no more than the one automatically generated by Xcode.